# Kafka Sink: ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:130)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Am trying to stream data from one stream file to another file. It was working earlier and suddenly it providing the error as `ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:130)`. Have restarted the zookeeper, kafka-server, schema-registry, source and sink connectors, but still am facing same issue and unable to resolve it. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Source connector:

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/home/jimmacaulay/Desktop/ETL/Kafka/confluent-5.5.1/data/data/Jim_Source.csv
topic=Jim
```

Sink connector:

```
name=local-file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=/home/jimmacaulay/Desktop/ETL/Kafka/confluent-5.5.1/data/data/Jim_Sink.csv
topics=Jim
```

Error:

```
[2020-08-18 06:25:50,482] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:130)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to initialize REST server
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:217)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:87)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8083
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:215)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the error by starting the `connect-standalone` using source and sink properties together.

```
sh connect-standalone ../config/connect-avro-standalone.properties ../config/connect-file-source_Topic_Jim.properties ../config/connect-file-sink_Topic_Jim.properties
```

Earlier i was starting it separately as below,

```
sh connect-standalone ../config/connect-avro-standalone.properties ../config/connect-file-source_Topic_Jim.properties

sh connect-standalone ../config/connect-avro-standalone.properties ../config/connect-file-sink_Topic_Jim.properties
```

Cause of the issue,

When am starting separately `connect-standalone` is getting started first for source properties using the port number 8083. Again when am starting the sink properties, it tries to use same port number and failes.

Solutions,

Both source and sink properties should be while starting `connect-standalone` which shares the same port.

Or define the different port numbers in the properties file and start it separately

Comment: Or use connect-distributed, which starts a single REST Server on one port, where you can run both connectors